# How to bind the control in Datalist with new value?

Tags: asp.net, html, video

> I did my code play video with **HTML5** video control , I did my cod well
>   to play video but it didn't work because i saved the video in db with
>   path " **~/res/Files/test.ogv** " the problem was  "**~/**" so i did my code
>   to remove " **~/**" to play the video . the problem is when I replace the
>   " **~/**" i want the HTML control pend the new value .

```
 protected void DL_Media_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        HtmlGenericControl video = e.Item.FindControl("vd") as HtmlGenericControl;
        HtmlGenericControl source = e.Item.FindControl("source") as HtmlGenericControl;
        string src = source.Attributes["src"].ToString();
        if (src != null)
        {
            string x = "~/";
            string y = " ";

              string result = src.Replace(x, y);
              src = result;



        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this:

```
protected void DL_Media_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        HtmlGenericControl video = e.Item.FindControl("vd") as HtmlGenericControl;
        HtmlGenericControl source = e.Item.FindControl("source") as HtmlGenericControl;
        string src = source.Attributes["src"].ToString();
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(src))
        {           
            src = src.Replace("~/","");
        }
        source.Attributes["src"] = src;
    }
}
```